# How do i change the icon of an empty document to white?

Tags: text, document

I want to change color of empty document to white...

[image]

How I can do !!

Answer (score 0):

Enter **gedit** - go to its Preferences on the upper menubar (it is the second from the left) - there you can change Color scheme.